# Axis2 aar file structure question

Tags: java, apache-axis

I trying to create an Axis2 arr file that has 2 package heirachies. However my service class is throwing a class not found exception when it tries to use classes in the utils package.

Is it possible to do this in Axis? Any advice is very welcome.

Below is an example of the structure I am trying to create (utils and org are both top level packages)...

```
|- SampleService  
|-- META-INF  
|--- services.xml  
|-- utils  
|---MyUtils.class  
|-- org  
|---- apache  
|---- axis2  
|----- axis2userguide  
|------ SampleService.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
The aar file does exactly what I want. There was an issue with some other code which fooled us.

Sorry for wasting your time.
Alan